# Can I prevent the same commit to be tested multiple times on Travis CI?

Tags: git, travis-ci

We are using Travis CI to run tests automatically. Every time we push a commit to a branch or tag, the commit is being tested. But I'm using many branches and tags and many times the same commit is used in several branches and tags, and it's tested multiple times. Is it possible to prevent the same commit to be tested multiple times on Travis CI? I want each commit to be tested once, or maximum twice. Currently commits are tested 3 or 4 or even 6 times for the same commit.

[Our project on Travis CI.](https://travis-ci.org/speedy-net/speedy-net/branches)

You can see there that for example commit [b93c5a8](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/commit/b93c5a821a1c2d1086154cb59389044d721861eb) was tested 6 times (2 tags, 4 branches).

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to your git policies and workflow, but you can specify which branches you want build using the `branch` property in your `.travis.yml`.

For example, we only have `master`, `staging`, and `develop` being built and tested. We work on various branches into `develop` for code review. When we're ready for final testing and build status, we PR into `staging` or `master` which triggers Travis. When reviews and testing pass, we merge into `master` or `staging` which deploys to production or staging respectively.

```sh
branch:
  - master
  - staging
```

Ours is also set up to auto cancel a current build if a new merge is added to the PR - that's done via the Travis ui. You can do more like testing tags, etc using scripts in your `.travis.yml`, but we haven't found a need for that in our workflow yet.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know. Where is the specification for branches to test? Is it possible to include wildcards?

Comment: Is it possible to test any branch if the commit is new and hasn't been tested before?

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#building-specific-branches